# Java: Extending a class instead of performing same logic in too many classes. Pros and Cons?

Tags: java

There is a logic and properties used to create certain object. That logic is going to repeated in several classes. Like some template logic. *e.g.* suppose I am creating a template to create enums like objects, which basically requires setting an int in constructor and getting value through method.

There are two ways to do this

1. Create a template superclass which has both of these logics, and extending it whenever we need to create an enum like object.
2. Create and re write both the logics every where.

Keeping memory and performance of code in mind which option is preferable. What are the pros and cons for it?

Comment: Your question is too vague for anyone to provide anything but the most general of answers.  Perhaps you can provide some example code or a more detailed description of your problem domain.  In general, re-use rather than code repetition is clearly better.

Comment: You `extend` some type by another type *if and only if* they are related in a "IS-A" relation. It does not appear to be the case by your description here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always memory consumption and performance are secondary to readability and maintainability.

If I were you, I would sit down and think about **where the logic belongs logically**, and put it there. You could for instance ask yourself, *Which solution would be easiest for me to defend for someone reading my code for the first time?*

If the logic sort of spans across all subclasses (i.e. if you can't extend the class without dealing with this logic) put it in the super class.

If the logic is truly specific to all subclasses, then put it in the subclasses.

If you go for the later, consider writing it in a way such that you can enforce the logic to be implemented through **abstract methods** in the super class.

---

(BTW, your question, and the enum-tag isn't really clear. You can't instantiate enums in runtime in Java.)

Comment: I have heard that Enums were not there before j2se 5.0. In case If my target j2se is below that and I want to give a class an enum behavior I have to write the code manually.... I hope the point in question is clear enough to you. For tag, yes I am removing it, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Ok, I see. It still seems like a bad idea to create the enum objects in runtime. In this case I would strongly encourage you to have a private constructor / factory method and make sure you have exactly one instance per constant.

Comment: 1.5 came out in 2004 and completed its End Of Service Life period some time ago. I think the only reasonable justification for targeting 1.4 is if you want to still work on Java ME.

Comment: @aioobe : According to you I should go for option 2. Write same logic in every class, is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @PrashamTrivedi, that's ultimately up to you to judge. *I* can't say which decision you would have the easiest time to defend to someone who reads your code for the first time...

Answer (score 1):

This feels like the territory of the Single Responsibility principle. What you are saying seems to suggest you should pull out the functionality into another class and compose it into the respective objects (i.e each object has one of the 'helper' object, or maybe all reference the same helper object). Extending isn't the only way of re-using code!

Comment: Not only is inheritance not the only way to use code, it's generally not a particularly good way either.